# Reserved keyword rule in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm new to Antlr4.

There is g4 grammar rules:

```
Function
: first
| second
| third
;

first
: FIRST'(' (STRING) (',' firstMode)? ')'
;

firstMode
: A
| B
;

A
: '"' F I R S T '"'
;

B
: '"'F I R S T D A Y'"'
;

STRING
: '"' .*? '"'
;
```

I want "FIRST" to be A in the context of FIRST("string", "FIRST")
and normally when I write "FIRST" or aa "FIRST" or something like them, I hope "FIRST" would be String type. How to get what I want?

Comment: Did you write [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342155/tokenizing-predefined-keywords-as-strings-in-specific-contexts-with-antlr) too (it looks like that), but under a different account?

Comment: Hi @MikeLischke, I rewrote it again with more details :) But maybe it would be confusing as well. I will delete. Thanks!